# Difference in object construction using "X x(42)" and "X x = 42"?

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit-constructor

Let's say we have class X with defined constructor `X(int value)`.

Is this semantically equivalent or not?

```
X x = 42;
X x(42);
```

I believe the difference will appear only if we add **explicit** keyword to constructor of X.
Otherwise compiler will reduce expression `X x = 42;` to `X x(42);`

Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form

```
X x = 42;
```

requires that the constructor be non-explicit and that there be an accessible copy-constructor. The implementation is allowed to construct a temporary and copy it over, but no implementation I know of does that.

Comment: Would that bypass an explicit assignment operator?  I would've thought it'd take that route.  But my brain's admittedly been a bit fuzzy.

Comment: No, it's not allowed to construct a temporary. Are you confusing it with `X x = X(42)`?

Comment: @Pubby : Yes it is -- this is called _copy initialization_ for a reason. ;-] Though in practice, it will always be elided.

Comment: @MichaelWilson: There is no *assignment-operator* in that syntax.

Comment: @Pubby, what ildjarn said. In fact, to be more precise, the standard actually directly says that a temporary is created and then copied. It is due to copy-elision rules that implementations are allowed to construct the object directly.

Comment: @innochenti, um, strictly subjectively, you should accept mine. :)

Comment: @Pubby Yes, that's precisely what I'm confusing it with.  I've been working purely with perl for too long.  Thanks o/

Answer (score 5):

Semantically the two operations are different per the language in the specification, but the effective results after compilation are the same in the following circumstances:

1. There is a single argument constructor for `X` that can take an integral-type and the argument type is not a non-const l-value reference
2. There is a single argument constructor for `X` where an integral-type can be converted to the argument type, and where the argument is again not a non-const l-value reference
3. In the case of #2, the constructor is not declared as `explicit`